# How to remove the edit line at the bottom of a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I am using a `DataGridView` in a UI because of how easy it is to bind to a source like a `DataTable`. The only problem I have is that it is intended to be read only and therefore I don't need the edit line that always shows up at the bottom of the grid rows. I have looked around and can't see a way to turn it off. Dose anyone know of a way to remove it?

The edit line is the one at the bottom of the table with the triangle and the star in the column all the way in the left column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `AllowUserToAddRows` to `false`

Comment: Absolutely what i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Set `ReadOnly = true` and **all** the edit features (including new rows) will be hidden. For more granularity, look at the `AllowUserTo*` properties.